# OpenGL - glReadPixels returns incorrect values

Tags: arrays, opengl, pixel

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't find anything wrong with the code. It's for testing purposes, and all it's supposed to do is set the color of all pixels to white and read the pixel information. The result is an array full of 0s.

```
    unsigned int frameBuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);
    unsigned int texture;
    unsigned int depthTexture;
    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glGenTextures(1,&depthTexture);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);

    int w = 256;
    int h = 256;

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RGB,
        w,h,
        0,GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        0
    );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture,0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTexture);
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,
        w,h,
        0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
        GL_FLOAT,
        0
    );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTexture,0);

    int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        unsigned char *pixels = new unsigned char[w *h *3];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<(w *h *3);i++)
            pixels[i] = 255;
        glDrawPixels(w,h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&pixels[0]);
        glReadPixels(0,0,w,h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&pixels[0]);
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<(w *h *3); i+=3)
        {
            unsigned int r = pixels[i];
            unsigned int g = pixels[i + 1];
            unsigned int b = pixels[i + 2];
            std::cout<<i<<": "<<r<<","<<g<<","<<b<<std::endl;
        }
        delete[] pixels;
        int err = glGetError(); // No error reported
    }
    glBindTexture(0,GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindFramebuffer(0,GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

No errors reported and the frame buffer is fine. What's going on here?

Comment: Is the depth test enabled when this code is executed? You add a depth buffer to the FBO, but never clear it before starting to draw.

Comment: Disabling the depth test and removing the depth attachment from the frame buffer doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone found out the cause on a different forum.

The solution is to call

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
```

before calling glReadPixels, and

```
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
```

afterwards, to reset it.

Comment: Good that you solved your problem, but something is fishy here. Either your OpenGL implementation is broken, or there is something going on in code that was not in the question. Are you calling `glReadBuffer()` anywhere else in your code? The `READ_BUFFER` state is per framebuffer object, and the default for an FBO is `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. So these calls should be completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that the raster position is valid for [glDrawPixels](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) before the call:

```
glRasterPos(0,0);
glDrawPixels(w,h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glReadPixels(0,0,w,h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Comment: I tried using glRasterPos2f(0.f,0.f); before the draw/read calls, but nothing changed.

Comment: If you read out the pixels between the Draw and Read calls, are they still all 0? I wonder if it's Read or Draw that's setting them to something other than 255

Comment: No, between the draw and read calls the values are the same as I specified them, so it's the read call that changes them to 0.

Comment: You could try `glWindowPos2f(0.0f, 0.0f)` instead of `glRasterPos`. If you have transformations set up, they are applied to the position passed to `glRasterPos`, which you wouldn't want in this case.